# jquery 'load()' event methods is not working inside jquery ready() event method on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tested on firefox mobile and chrome mobile browser. Perfectly working on computer browsers

Here is my code inside `ready()` and `load()` event method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('load hashchange', function(event) {
       alert();
    });
});
```

Why `alert()` is not working after page completed loading.

And here is my another code:

```
$(function({
   $.ajaxSetup({
    headers : {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
   });
});
$(window).on('load hashchange', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
      //ajax request faild due to csrf token mismatch
    });
});
```

I didn't found any `X-CSRF-TOKEN` request header on chrome devtools.

According to the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp) 'The `ready()` method should not be used together with `<body onload="">`'. But I'm not using any html inline `load` event. Please help me to find out this issue.

I'm using jquery v3.6.0 on my project. Also I used usb remote debugging for check request headers.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Chrome Desktop** `$(document).ready(fn)` will run ***before*** `$(window).on('load', fn)`.

In Desktop/Mobile Firefox and Mobile Chrome, `ready` runs *after* `load`.

Try:

```js
const print = (s) => out.innerHTML += '\n' + s;
$(document).ready(function() { print('ready'); });
$(window).on('load', function() { print('load'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

So, you shouldn't rely on their order for code that has some kind of time-related coupling.

For instance, you could run both on either `ready` or `load`, or even run that `.ajaxSetup` directly (not wrapped into a `ready`).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answers, that means codes inside ready function is executing after load function executes. That's why I'm not getting any headers included request. Thanks again for solve this

Comment: As noted in the answer, but worth re-iterating:  doc.ready is there to run code when the DOM is has finished loading and is ready for manipulation.   Your `$.ajaxSetup({` needs the meta tag from the `header` so should be ok to run immediately, without needing to be in a doc.ready or onload - as long as your code exists in the page content after that `meta` tag